# Does a ThunderBolt cable increase resolution on a monitor or just frame rate?

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt

I'm curious what does having a ThunderBolt display over others mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are two questions here - one about Thunderbolt cables and another about a Mac mini maximum resolution.  Please limit to one question and provide sufficient details so we accurately answer the question.

Comment: @Allan sorry I will post the second question in a different post.

Comment: Keep in mind that, as written, both are off topic; the Thunderbolt cable question for not being about Apple products and the Mac mini resolution question being too broad and potentially a dupe.  Just some helpful hints as you rework the question(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) A cable cannot "increase" the resolution of one source to a destination. However, if the cable provided more bandwidth than your previous cable, the system would seem to upgrade the speed because of the extra bandwidth available.

Think of it in terms of a highway with cars. If your old cable is only a two-lane highway, you can only put a certain amount of cars on it. Now if your new cable is an 8-lane expressway, then you can put so many more cars on it and even though the speed of the cars does not necessarily increase, there are more cars and more bandwidth and less traffic.

B) As for the LG Electronics 34UM88-P, it supports thunderbolt 2.0 as well as DisplayPort - both of these are supported on the Mac Mini.

Source: https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34UM88-P-ultrawide-monitor

Comment: Thanks, so basically with thunderbolt you will have more framerate per second?

Comment: Depends on the monitor. You measure monitor refresh rate with Hz. So if the monitor is 120Hz, you get 120 refreshes per second. FPS is used for games and is dependent on a multitude of options like graphics card etc. If you have any specific question to gaming, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate cable will allow a monitor to achieve its max resolution but it will not change or increase the max resolution of the monitor - that is down to the design of the monitor.